# Print binary then negate without ones complement in python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, negate

i'm new to python and tried to do something like that:

```
a=23
"{0:b}".format(a)

---> '10111'
```

then i want to negate it WITHOUT ones complement, the result should be '01000' but nothing seems to work

secondly i would have to fill up the left side with 0's, i found something like

```
"{0:12b}".format(a)
'       10111'
```

but it just makes the string longer filling it up with blanks

EDIT: the perfect solution for me would be

```
"{0:12b}".format(a)
'000000010110' 
"{0:12b}".format(~a)
'111111101001'
```

(which of course doesnt work this way)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a `0` in front of the `12` to left-pad the output with zeroes.

```
In [1]: "{0:012b}".format(a)
Out[1]: '000000010111'
```

For the ones comp, the you could do string manipulation, or the math way:

```
 In [2]: "{0:012b}".format(2**12-1-a)
 Out[2]: '111111101000'
```

Just change the `2**12` to the number of digits you want to display

Comment: yes that worked thanks, you have a solution for my other (main) problem too?

Comment: for one's comp of a specific length, you can also use xor: `0xfff ^ num`.

Comment: 2**12 is 1 followed 12 zeroes. Subtract 1 and you get 12 ones. Subtracting anything from all ones switches the bits. `1-1=0` and `1-0=1`.  Basically it's doing the `xor` operation that @CorleyBrigman describes.